# can I upload same app with diffrent app name?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I have an iphone app. I want to upload this app 2 times in itune with different name.

is it possible?

Comment: I doubt apple would approve an identical app for sale unless there was a reason for them being different, are they in different languages?

Comment: no but some content are different.

Comment: If some content is different, do not be worried. I have two applications like this. One application is in 4 variants and other is in 10. But UI resources (images) are also different.

Comment: But my UI are same for both app.

Comment: This may be OK too. I just wanted to share my experience and say that everything was good. They can't check every app in the App Strore. But in review guidelines you can find that app that duplicates functionality of another app may be rejected. It is mostly related to apps like flashlight or Kama sutra.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store approval policies.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you should also change Bundle ID and maybe you'll have to desribe the reason of it for Apple guys.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

> **2.11** Apps that duplicate Apps already in the App Store **may be rejected**,
>   particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp,
>   flashlight, and Kama Sutra Apps

Pay attention to the phrase "may be rejected". As someone experienced told me, this rule exists to prevent cluttering App Store with apps where, for example, only a color of the background changes. If you provide different content, than it's different user experience and as a result - different app.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload an application more than 2 times in itunes. Your applications must have own unique Bundle Identifier to Upload or you already can't see your app in Application Loader.

But there is a point, if you will not describe why you upload the same application with different name in itunes (with different Bundle Identifier), Apple will going to reject your application with description "App Duplication"..

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to be sure if it'll be rejected. But I highly doubt that it'll get caught with a different name. We have done it before, to transfer an app to a different account. (Before app transfer was introduced.)

Just remember to change the your bundle identifier - and the provisioning file of course. :-)